# Lifetime of reference to self returned from iterator

Tags: rust, lifetime

Is it possible to implement an iterator that returns a reference to an object cached in the iterator itself? I'm writing a matrix and vector library just for fun/as a learning exercise and can't get this to work. Would like not to allocate a new vector each iteration.

```
use crate::{Number, Matrix, Vector};

pub struct RowIter<'a, const X: usize, const Y: usize, T: Number>
where [T; X * Y]: Sized {
    matrix: &'a Matrix<X, Y, T>,
    index: usize,
    row: Vector<{ X * Y }, T>
}

impl<'a, const X: usize, const Y: usize, T: Number> RowIter<'a, X, Y, T>
where [T; X * Y]: Sized {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(matrix: &'a Matrix<X, Y, T>) -> Self {
        Self {
            matrix,
            index: 0,
            row: Vector::from([T::default(); X * Y])
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, const X: usize, const Y: usize, T: Number> std::iter::Iterator for RowIter<'a, X, Y, T>
where [T; X * Y]: Sized {
    type Item = &Vector<{ X * Y }, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index >= Y {
            return None;
        }

        let yoffset = self.index * X;
        self.row.data_mut().copy_from_slice(&self.matrix.data()[yoffset..yoffset + X]);

        self.index += 1;

        Some(&self.row)
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        (0, Some(Y - self.index))
    }
}
```